# VSCode Jupyter - Plots displaying differently in different files despite using same backend

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to plot some data using the VSCode Jupyter Notebook editor. Not sure if that's relevant.

Here is the code for generating my plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

```
G = 32.2  # [ft/s^2]

v_0 = 8  # [ft/s]
theta = 45  # [deg]

theta_rad = theta * np.pi/180

x_0 = 0  # [ft]
v_0x = v_0 * np.cos(theta_rad)  # [ft/s]
a_x = 0  # [ft/s^2]

y_0 = 3  # [ft]
v_0y = v_0 * np.sin(theta_rad)  # [ft/s]
a_y = -G  # [ft/s^2]

t_final = (v_0y + np.sqrt(v_0y**2 + 2*G*y_0)) / G
```

```
N = 50
t = np.linspace(0, t_final, N)

x = x_0  +  v_0x*t  +  1/2 * a_x * t**2
y = y_0  +  v_0y*t  +  1/2 * a_y * t**2

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(x, y)

ax.set_xlim(left=0)
ax.set_ylim(bottom=0)

ax.set_aspect('equal')

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Trying this code in the first `.ipynb` file results in this plot:

[image]

Trying this code in a different `.ipynb` file results in this plot:

[image]

When running `matplotlib.get_backend()` both files return `'module://matplotlib_inline.backend_inline'`.

This behavior persists after restarting VSCode and my PC, and seems to depend on the file somehow.

Why is this happening? How can I force VSCode/Jupyter to use the style in the second plot?

Comment: Are you using the same kernel?

Comment: @Steven-MSFT Yes, both are using Python 3.8.10 64bit

Comment: It seems like there is an important difference in the .ipynb JSON properties between the files. In the first file the value of the property `metadata` is `{"needs_background": "light"}`. In the second file the value is simply `{}`.

Comment: Furthermore the lines:
```import seaborn as sns;
sns.set()```
Seem to achieve my desired effect of forcing the format to look like the second image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the library I was importing was calling `sns.set()` internally